# Determine if a matrix is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

This is the matrix given:

\begin{bmatrix}
   a & a & a \\ b & b & b \\ c& c & c \\
  \end{bmatrix}

I'm not very well-versed in linear algebra, so I'll explain what I do understand, feel free to correct me on any of it.

If this matrix is shown to have 3 distinct eigenvalues (and thus 3 distinct eigenvectors?), then it is diagonalizable. This is because with 3 distinct eigenvalues, there are 3 linearly independent vectors, and they form a basis.

A diagonalized matrix would be a matrix with only values in the diagonal.

How can it be shown that there are three distinct eigenvalues (or not) for this matrix?

Comment: calcuate the determinant and show for what values of the parameters it is not zero.  pretty simple

Comment: If it has 3 distinct eigenvalues then you can say that it is diagonalizable. However the converse is not true. Even if it does not have 3 distinct eigenvalues, it doesnt mean that the matrix is necessarily not diagonalizable. Perhaps you can start by computing the characteristic polynomial for this matrix?

Answer (score 3):

The characteristic polynomial is
$$det \begin{pmatrix}
a-\lambda&a&a\\
b&b-\lambda&b\\
c&c&c-\lambda\\
\end{pmatrix}=-\lambda^3+(a+b+c)\lambda^2$$
This has solutions $\lambda = 0$ and $\lambda = a+b+c$. Thus the eigenvalues are not all distinct. It also has eigenvectors $(-1,0,1)$, $(-1,1,0)$, and $(a/c, b/c, 1)$. If you pick $a$, $b$, and $c$ so that these eigenvectors are linearly independent then you can diagonalize the matrix. As DietrichBurde says we can't have $a+b+c=0$.

Comment: I might’ve instead chosen $(a,b,c)^T$ as the third eigenvector since we might have $c=0$.

Answer (score 2):

The column rank is obviously $1$, if not $a=b=c=0$, so that the Jordan normal form is given by
$J=diag(0,0,a+b+c)$, for $a+b+c\neq 0$, since the trace equals $a+b+c$. Hence, for $a+b+c\neq 0$ the matrix is diagonalisable. For $a+b+c=0$ the matrix is not diagonalizable.